# Excel Conditional Formatting based on date range - workdays only

Tags: excel

I'm pretty new to Excel, and one of my bosses (who knows even less about Excel than I) is asking me to create a spreadsheet that will track a bunch of different deadlines.  For quick reference, I need to use conditional formatting to do the following:

1. Highlight only non-blank cells that contain a date in the past.
2. Highlight with a color scale cells containing dates between now and now+90 workdays.

Nothing I've tried is giving me the results I need.  I'd appreciate any guidance, as I'm getting very frustrated and this is fairly time-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer your second question. I think you will be able to answer the first one yourself from what you learn from the second one.

The executive summary is: use a combination of `TODAY()` and `WORKDAY()`.

Now for some useful detail.

First, I suspect (from your reputation) that you are new to StackOverflow. Welcome! Take a look on the right side of this page. At the bottom there are "Related" questions. I obtained the following one from there. It is half of the answer to your question. The key point is to [use the `TODAY()` function in your formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900446/microsoft-excel-conditional-formatting-of-dates-within-certain-ranges?rq=1).

Second, [the `WORKDAY()` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-function-c3334471-ff31-4acb-b2cc-977a456e877c), with a positive number `n`, provides a date `n` workdays into the future. You may also need to make adjustments if your company's calendar is different from the canonical one.

You may want to set a cell in your spreadsheet to the date returned by `=WORKDAY(TODAY(),90)`. Lets just pick `A1` for simplicity of explanation. When you first add that formula, you will get what seems like a nonsensical number. Change that cell's format to date and it will make sense.

Now you can refer to `A1` in your conditional formatting, as in the "less than" highlighting rule. That should do it.

P.S., while you are at it, search for "named ranges". As a beginner, it is probably the most useful "trick" you could learn. Then name whatever your `A1` cell turns out to be something meaningful, like `ninetyWorkdaysAhead` (you cannot start a named range with a number), then refer to that name in your rule. That way, if you need to move it, your code will not break.